# Why contract owner balance 1Token instead of 1000000 in Metamask

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I made contract ERC20 token MTCZx

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf9471198b6f9c364f41Ea66e9a3F8daA637Ee77C#code

which can sell MTCZx tokens for ETH.

When I deployed it I make query to **balanceOf** with contract owner

> 0x1b7c7eb39ee32aeC901Ddcf50b5b46dE13E74931

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xf9471198b6f9c364f41Ea66e9a3F8daA637Ee77C#readContract

and see contract owner has 1 000 000 MTCZx balance.

When I add MTCZx to metamask I see balance only 1 MTCZx instead of 1 000 000.

The same 1 MTCZx total supply here instead of 1 000 000

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0xf9471198b6f9c364f41Ea66e9a3F8daA637Ee77C

Also when I send tokens to another user https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xdcfc79ff803eda40f9a7841c84acb76434565be9fb120bc3fbdfb2f46793d7ae

I see in Metamask balance 0 tokens instead of 0.01 MTCZx

What's wrong with metamask? I or ERC20 contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denomination unit in your ERC20 contract is 6:

```
uint8 public constant decimals = 6;
```

MetaMask displays the balance according to this value, i.e., the balance divided by `10 ** 6`.